# knockout -binding the visibility of a input field in a template based on its position in its parents child list

Tags: templates, knockout.js, data-binding

I have coded a knockout template example that allows the user to create a group of groups.  (simplified version of what i am doing)  In each instance of a group (which is a template) I have a logic selection input box.  I want to make that input box not display if the group row is the first in side a parent group.

So to do this i created a ko.computed function named **visibleLogicLink** and used that in the data bind for styles to set the visibility; but this is not working.

Can anyone give me guides how to make this work?

[image showing the current code output compared to what I am trying to get as output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDN7R.png)

**In my fiddle: [fiddle example of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/bkhummingbird/q0mdw09z)   (code also added below)**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/queryBuilder/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="../libs/knockout.js"></script>
<script>
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~group~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
window.QueryBuilder = (function(exports, ko) {
  var Condition = exports.Condition;
  /**
   * creates an instants of the group template.
   */
  function Group() {
    var self = this;
    self.templateName = 'group-template';
    self.children = ko.observableArray();
    self.logicalGrpOperators = ko.observableArray(['AND', 'OR']);

    self.visibleLogicLink = ko.computed(function(child) {
      if (0 == self.children.indexOf(child))
        return "hidden";
      else
        return "visible";
    });

    self.addGroup = function() {
      self.children.push(new Group());
    };
    self.removeChild = function(child) {
      self.children.remove(child);
    };
  }
  exports.Group = Group;
  return exports;
})(window.QueryBuilder || {}, window.ko);
//~~~~~~~~~~view model~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
window.QueryBuilder = (function(exports, ko) {
  var Group = exports.Group;
  function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.group = ko.observable(new Group());
  }
  exports.ViewModel = ViewModel;
  return exports;
})(window.QueryBuilder || {}, window.ko);
</script>
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~MODEL~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<div class="container">
  <div data-bind="with: group">
    <div data-bind="template: templateName"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~group-template~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<script type="text/html" id="group-template">
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-group" style="border-width: 5px;border-color:blue;">

    <select data-bind="options: logicalGrpOperators,
            style:{'visibility' : $parent.visibleLogicLink }">
      </select> this thing

    <button data-bind="click: addGroup">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Group
      </button>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.removeChild">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span> Remove Group
      </button>
    <div class="group-conditions">
      <div data-bind="foreach: children">
        <div data-bind="template: templateName"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new QueryBuilder.ViewModel());
  }, true);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pointers:

1. A `ko.computed` doesn't take any parameters. I.e., this does not make sense:

   ```
   self.visibleLogicLink = ko.computed(function(child) { /* ... */ })
   ```
2. Your `ViewModel` level does not implement the `visibleLogicLink` property you rely on in your view (`$parent.visibleLogicLink`)
3. It's easier to use the `visible` binding and return `true` or `false`, rather than using the `style` binding with `"hidden"` and `"visible"`.

A solution could be to implement `visibleLogicLink` as a regular method:

```
// In `Group`
self.visibleLogicLink = function(child) {
  return self.children.indexOf(child) !== 0;
};

// In `ViewModel`
self.visibleLogicLink = function() { return false; };
```

And then rewrite the binding to:

```
visible: $parent.visibleLogicLink($data)
```

I've added these change to your fiddle so you can see them [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/3j4y13zh/1/)